# Roblox Studio error: ServerScriptService.Script:15: attempt to index nil with 'CharacterAdded'

Tags: lua, roblox

I was just going over a script and I ran into an error I don't really know how to fix. If anybody can help I'd appreciate it! (Line 15,attempt to index nil with 'CharacterAdded' error.)

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local blurDelay = 0 --seconds
local blurDuration = 6 --seconds
local blurEffect = Instance.new("BlurEffect")
blurEffect.Size = 0
blurEffect.Enabled = false
blurEffect.Parent = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
local tween

local function createTween()
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(blurDuration, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.Out, 0, false, blurDelay)
    return TweenService:Create(blurEffect, tweenInfo, {Size = 56})
end

game.Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
    local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    if tween and tween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing then
        tween:Cancel()
    end
    blurEffect.Size = 0
    blurEffect.Enabled = false
    humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
        blurEffect.Enabled = true
        tween = createTween()
        tween:Play()
    end)
end)
```

EDIT:

- I tried to switch it to a ''Local Script'', Not just ''script'' still doesn't work. And I tried to switch it from ServerScriptService to StarterGUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error, because if you put this code into a regular Script on the server, there is no LocalPlayer. You need to run it in a LocalScript and put that into StarterPlayerScripts. That will work just fine, exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerAdded`, use this instead: `game.Players.PlayerAdded`.