# Attempt to index nil

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a pickup, but an error pops up when you pick it up.
Here is the error:

```
Workspace.LogPickup.LogPickupScript:8: attempt to index nil with 'Parent'
```

Line 8 for the script is the variable player.

Here is the code:

```
local log = script.Parent
local logGuard = false

local function onTouch(partTouched)
    
    local character = partTouched.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent)
    local playerStats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    local playerLogCount = playerStats:FindFirstChild("Has Log")
    
    if humanoid and logGuard == false then
        
        log.Transparency = 1
        log.CanCollide = false
        logGuard = true
        playerLogCount.Value = 1
        
        wait(5)
        
        log.Transparency = 0
        log.CanCollide = true
        logGuard = false
        
    end
    
end

log.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: `humanoid` is `nil`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roblox Studio error: ServerScriptService.Script:15: attempt to index nil with 'CharacterAdded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574243/roblox-studio-error-serverscriptservice-script15-attempt-to-index-nil-with-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error tells you that you index a nil value with the key 'Parent' in line 8.

Indexing nil values is not allowed.

Search for any of the following in line 8:

```
.Parent
[Parent]
:Parent
```

and find:

```
humanoid.Parent
```

Now you know that humanoid is a nil value which you may not index.

Either make sure character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid") always returns the expected value or check if it does befor you index it.

```
local character = partTouched.Parent
local humanoid = character and  character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
local player = humanoid and game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(humanoid.Parent)
local playerStats = player and player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
local playerLogCount = playerStats and playerStats:FindFirstChild("Has Log")
```

Short-circuits are a simple way to avoid indexing errors as long as you can be sure that you either get nil or the expected value.